# Do references created by exec become invalid when no globals dict is passed?

Tags: python

**exec.py**:

```
def func1():
   pass
def required_func():
   func1()
from some_module import set_callback
set_callback(required_func)
```

**main.py**:

```
execfile('exec.py',dict())
call_callback() #indirectly calls required_func
```

I exec the file passing an empty dict() for globals. `required func` will have a reference saved in `some_module` but will `func1` will also be available to call?  Will `func1` be deleted as it is not in `globals()` or saved in any other object?

Comment: Why not check it out yourself? You've got the code already.

Comment: it does not work in shell if I explicitly `del func1` but with `execfile` it works. I don't understand how it works, hence can't rely on my test.

Comment: `func1`, `required_func` and `set_callback` are available to use through accessing the `dict()` you are passing to `execfile`. If you pass it a reference to a dict, you will be able to call those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont be deleted because when you define the function `required_func` it has a reference to the `globals` of its module:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> execfile('test.py', d)
>>> from some_module import f
>>> f
<function required_func at 0x7fb5649b5578>
>>> f.func_globals is d
True
```

If this wasn't true, then whenever you import a function into a different module the function would use the `globals` of that module. This is something you do *not* want.
There will be a big issue with namespace collision, so that some functions would start behaving in different ways depending on where they were imported.